# Search by field on different classes and different lists Java 8 Stream

Tags: java, list, lambda, collections, java-stream

I have three different lists with different objects. I need to go through each of the list, comparing one field and if it's the same, create new object.

```
ObjectA: firstName, id
ObjectB: email, id 
ObjectC: birthday, id
Model: firstName, email, birthday, id
```

Can I somehow using stream search through lists of object by id and on output create list of Models with mentioned fields?

I have tried this:

```
List<ObjectA> list1;
List<ObjectB> list2;
List<ObjectC> list3;
List<Model> output = list1.stream().flatMap(p -> list2.stream()
                                  .filter(t -> p.getId().equals(t.getId())).findFirst()
                                  .flatMap(t -> list3.stream()
                                  .filter(i -> t.getId().equals(i.getId())).findFirst()
.flatMap(i -> new Model(p, i, t)))) // Model has a constructor, that takes classes as values
.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not going to work with streams, streams are suitable to process homogenous data, which this isn't.

Step 1 is to turn your lists into maps, mapping id to the object in question.

Then, armed with the 3 maps, you can merge. First make a superset of all IDs, then for each ID, gather up your data, and create your object.

Something like:

```
Map<String, String> as = list1.stream()
  .collect(Collectors.toMap(ObjectA::getId, ObjectA::getName));
Map<String, String> bs = list2.stream()
  .collect(Collectors.toMap(ObjectB::getId, ObjectB::getEmail));
Map<String, LocalDate> cs = list3.stream()
  .collect(Collectors.toMap(ObjectC::getId, ObjectC::getBirthDate));

var allIds = new HashSet<String>();
allIds.addAll(as.keySet());
allIds.addAll(bs.keySet());
allIds.addAll(cs.keySet());

var objs = allIds.stream()
  .map(id -> new ModelObj(id,
     as.getOrDefault(id, "(NoName)"),
     bs.getOrDefault(id, "(NoEmail)"),
     cs.get(id)))
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: But if each class has more than two fields? Map will be no more relevant?

Comment: your question says: "One field". You've now moved the goalposts. If you have multiple fields, then you'd make a container class capturing this multi-field status and use that as key instead. Without the maps, you'd be rescanning every list completely for every entry, and thus you get a performance disaster.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @rzwitserloot. I need to compare objects by one field (id), so I could concatenate information about user from different lists. My fault, that I mentioned only two fields on every class, because they have more than one field, but I wrote one as an example.

Comment: My code does exactly what you want. It gathers by one field (id), and then merges them into one object. If you don't understand part of it, which part, maybe I can clarify.